# Plotting regression predictors

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization

In the case of multiple regression where I have dependent variable Y and two predictors X1 and X2 I would like to make a plot of their relationship before fitting a regression, however the plot function only allows the plotting of two variables at a time. for example `plot(x, y)` how can I look at the overall data then?

Comment: Have you had a look at 'scatterplot3d' ? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/scatterplot3d.pdf

Comment: ocram thanks! also normally do people use the 3d plot in the case of multiple regression or is it more common to plot make separate 2d plots with the dependent variable and each predictor?

Comment: More on **trellis displays**: http://stat.bell-labs.com/project/trellis/, http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html, http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/rgraphics.html, http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/, and http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/.

Comment: thanks, but I'm just wondering how one normally does it to check the relationship between variables before fitting models. Do you look at separate relationships for each predictor in a simple x,y plot?

Comment: With two covariates only, a 3D plot is probably the best way to present your data. However, with more than predictors, you do not have that possibility anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an instance like this, I would probably use ggplot2, as it excels at this kind of thing.

Assuming that your variables are Y, X1 and X2.

```
myplot<- ggplot(yourdataframe, aes(x=X1, y=Y, colour=X2))+layer(geom="point")
print(myplot)
```

That will plot X1 against Y with different colours representing values of X2. You can also call `geom="smooth", method="lm"` to get a plot of the regression line, and loess smoothers are also available. HTH.

Comment: @richimorrisroe: It would have been cool if you had attached an illustrative picture to your answer ;-) Nonetheless, +1

Comment: thanks but what i'm wondering is how to do it in General. If there are 'n' predictors and I want to see their relationship to the dependent variable. is it better to plot them individually or to look at each relationship simoultaneously?

Comment: @ocram i was in the process of switching computers, so was a little strapped for time.

Comment: @Dbr You can do both with `splom()` (from the `lattice` package) or `pairs()`, i.e. plot all your variables (predictors + response) in a *scatterplot matrix*. You can then add local smoothers, highlight possible outlying values etc.

Comment: @Dbr in addition, if you use the `psych` package you can use the `pairs.panels()` function which gives you the correlations, the distributions and the scatterplots.